# How to deploy the outlook add-in project via Teams toolkit

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, teams-toolkit

I'm new bee for Teams add-in dev. Thanks for help.

It's fine to dev/debug the outlook add-in project with the help of Teams toolkit. but how should I deploy it?
After running `npm run build`, the assets will be compiled into  folder.
But the manifest is manifest.json instead of manifest.xml.

Sideloading the Office Add-in...
Manifest package saved to C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\manifest.zip
running: npx @microsoft/teamsfx-cli@2.0.2-alpha.4f379e6ab.0 m365 sideloading --file-path C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\manifest.zip

Comment: Add-ins with the JSON manifest are still in preview, so Microsoft doesn't really have a way yet to deploy them for production. We hope to have that in the next few months. In the meantime you can sideload them following step 8 of this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/teams-toolkit-overview

Comment: @RickKirkham Any updates on deploying json manifest ? thanks !

Comment: @OhadLahav Add-ins with the JSON manifest are still in preview for at least another 2 months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of several methods to deploy your Office Add-in for testing or distribution to users.

| Method | Use... |
| --- | --- |
| Sideloading | As part of your development process, to test your add-in running on Windows, iPad, Mac, or in a browser. (Not for production add-ins.) |
| Network share | As part of your development process, to test your add-in running on Windows after you have published the add-in to a server other than localhost. (Not for production add-ins or for testing on iPad, Mac, or the web.) |
| AppSource | To distribute your add-in publicly to users. |
| Microsoft 365 admin center | In a cloud deployment, to distribute your add-in to users in your organization by using the Microsoft 365 admin center. This is done through Integrated Apps or Centralized Deployment. |
| SharePoint catalog | In an on-premises environment, to distribute your add-in to users in your organization. |
| Exchange server | In an on-premises or online environment, to distribute Outlook add-ins to users. |

Read about all of them in the [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) article.